# Make a change on a site package so original can include it on their next release

Tags: git, github

How do I make a custom change on a site package where the original owners can then review and include as part of the official code?

I'm using [django-adminaction rel 0.3](https://github.com/saxix/django-adminactions) which is hosted on GitHub.

I have a small issue I want to fix for my project and maybe upload it back to GitHub, so next release of adminaction can include the use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add it as a submodule to your project, and make changes in your own fork.

---

On Github, fork the repo to your own profile account and then add it as a submodule in your project repo at the path `bundle/adminactions`.

```
git submodule add git@github.com:[Ohad the Lad]/django-adminactions bundle/adminactions
git add bundle/adminactions
git commit -m 'Added nested git repo to my django project`
```

This will configure the repo with `origin` as your profile's version of the repo. I would also add the `upstream` repository from `saxix/django-adminactions` so that you can pull in upstream changes.

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/saxix/django-adminactions
```

---

So now you should have two remote repositories set up:

```
patrick@cyrus:~/bundle/adminactions(develop)$ git remote -v
    origin      git@github.com:[username]/django-adminactions.git (fetch)
    origin      git@github.com:[username]/django-adminactions.git (push)
    upstream    https://github.com/saxix/django-adminactions (fetch)
    upstream    https://github.com/saxix/django-adminactions (push)
```

---

Now, in your project, instead of importing it as usual (e.g. `import adminactions.actions as actions`) you import it from the new path:

`import bundle.adminactions.actions as actions`

---

To make an pull request from your fork to the `upstream` `saxix/django-adminactions.git` project, you should create a new branch and push it to your `origin` remote.

```
cd bundle/adminactions
git checkout -b feature/new_feature_name
[ make changes to your files here ]
git commit -m 'New widget & gizmo  (1 of 2) widget does X  (2 of 2) gizmo does Y'
git push --set-upstream origin feature/new_feature
```

---

Now your changes are staged in an distinct branch on your repo.  You can now access https://www.github.com/[Ohad the Lad]/django-adminactions and make a pull request.

Assuming you have indeed pushed your `new_feature` branch there will be a green button labeled "Compared & pull request" which will allow you to send your changes to `saxix/django-adminactions` upstream.

---

**TIP #1**: *If you are changing several different features of the application, I would stage each of them in a separate `feature/` branch on your `origin` repostitory.  E.g. `origin/feature/new_feature_one` and `origin/feature/new_feature_two`.*

**TIP #2**: *As a `git submodule` your parent folder, the django website project, does not see all the files in the `bundle/adminactions`. It only sees `adminactions` with a specific commit (e.g. `django-adminactions.git @ 3c57c96aafaa48c821caacb9f7b9589b7957bfe1`. When you checkout a different branch/commit in the nested submodule folder, to update the parent django project to require this version, you just `git add bundle/adminactions` and `git commit -m 'Checked out newer version of django-adminactions`.*

**TIP #3**: As the `upstream` repo may continue to make changes after when you forked the repo, it can be useful to frequently merge upstream changes into your `origin` repository to maintain consistency. The alias command I use, `mup` which means "merge upstream", may be helpful to you.

```
# ~/.gitconfig
# ...
[alias]
    unstage = reset HEAD --
    uncommit = reset --soft HEAD^
    mup = !"git fetch origin -v; git fetch upstream -v; git merge upstream/master"
    pullall = !"git pull; git submodule update --init --recursive"
```